# Verify brand name of installed SFP on Cisco Switch

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst, cisco-commands

I know I can run the `sh inv` to view the SFPs model and Serial Numbers attached on a Cisco Switch.

Is there a way to verify the **brand** name of each SFP?

I have Cisco 9300 and 9606 switches.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `show interface transceiver` (optional "detail")

```
transceiver is present
    type is 10Gbase-SR
    name is CISCO-AVAGO
    part number is [...]
    revision is B5
    serial number is [...]
    nominal bitrate is 10300 MBit/sec
    Link length supported for 50/125um OM2 fiber is 82 m
    Link length supported for 62.5/125um fiber is 26 m
    Link length supported for 50/125um OM3 fiber is 300 m
    cisco id is --
    cisco extended id number is 4
    cisco part number is 10-2415-02
    cisco product id is SFP-10G-SR
    cisco vendor id is V02
```

Comment: As I recall, you can even get a literal hex dump of the entire idprom.

Comment: `show interface transceiver` Only shows me the current and dBm levels.

Comment: `sh idprom interface` Does show the vendor name. Is there a way to run this command for all interfaces instead of one by one?